# Devolver 1 dupla por Id SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT IdentificadorAutomovil, Automovil.Titulo, Automovil.Precio, Automovil.Anio, Automovil.Kilimetros, Automovil.Ubicacion, Imagenes.Imagenes 

FROM Automovil INNER JOIN Imagenes

ON Automovil.IdentificadorAutomovil = Imagenes.Automovil
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera que solo me devuelva 1 dupla por Identificador Automovil , y no puedo lograr esto ,

Comment: El tema es que aparentemente tienes más de una Imagen por `IdentificadorAutomovil`, que quieres hacer con ellas? Agrega a la pregunta  un ejemplo de lo que quieres obtener. Saludos

Comment: Si tengo varias imagenes con el mismo ID pero solo quiero que me devuelva 1 dupla por ID no se puede?

Comment: El tema es que datos quieres obtener, si agregas el path de la imagen a tu salida, y habiendo más de una imagen, vas a tener si o si más de un registro por `IdentificadorAutomovil`, si no te interesa este dato, tampoco tiene sentido hacer un `JOIN` a  `Imagenes`. Por eso te decía que armes un ejemplo de la salida que quieres obtener para clarificar el tema.

Comment: Cuando hay una operación de combinación (JOIN) la cantidad de filas resultantes se da en función de las coincidencias resueltas en las expresiones de la cláusula ON o WHERE, por ejemplo, si tienes dos filas en la tabla 'Imagenes' que corresponden a un automóvil entonces queda claro que tras la combinación obtendrás dos filas, en consecuencia, si sólo deseas mostrar una fila debes decidir como mostrar los valores "diferentes", ¿el primero? ¿el último? ¿transponer los valores de fila a columnas?, tú decides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) (de forma eficiente) para obtener el primero de cada fila.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    A.IdentificadorAutomovil
   ,A.Titulo
   ,R.Imagenes
FROM Automovil A
    CROSS APPLY
( 
    SELECT TOP 1 I.Imagenes
    FROM Imagenes I
    WHERE I.Automovil = A.IdentificadorAutomovil
) R
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/EPID76219)

Answer (score 1):

En caso de que quieras agrupar por automovil te resultaría usando el operador GROUP BY de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT
    IdentificadorAutomovil ,
    Automovil.Titulo ,
    Automovil.Precio ,
    Automovil.Anio ,
    Automovil.Kilimetros ,
    Automovil.Ubicacion ,
    Imagenes.Imagenes
FROM
    Automovil
    INNER JOIN Imagenes ON Automovil.IdentificadorAutomovil = Imagenes.Automovil

GROUP BY 
    IdentificadorAutomovil,
    Automovil.Titulo ,
    Automovil.Precio ,
    Automovil.Anio ,
    Automovil.Kilimetros ,
    Automovil.Ubicacion ,
    Imagenes.Imagenes
```

El tema es que si la columna de imagenes difiere una de otra te va a seguir trayendo 2 registros, ya que te muestra una imagen por registro.